# Check 3 table from database while kept the information of each table for authenticate login form php

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication, database-normalization

I have tables like this

**Employee**

```
Id | IdEmployee  | Employee | Address     | Phone_num | 
1  | EM10000     |  Jack    | wall st.    | 9000010   | 
2  | EM10001     |  Paul    | elm st.     | 9000010   |
3  | EM10002     |  George  | ex  st .    | 9000010   |
```

**Technician**

```
id | IdTech      | TechName | Address      | phone_num | 
1  | TE10000     | Gabut    | Hello st.    | 9000010   | 
2  | TE10001     | Polnaref | coding st.   | 9000010   |
3  | TE10002     | Rafioli  | stack st.    | 9000010   |
```

**Admin**

```
id | IdAdmin     | username | password     | phone_num | 
1  | AM10000     |  sim1    | 1234         | 9000010   | 
2  | AM10001     |  sim2    | luvcoding    | 9000010   |
3  | AM10002     |  sim3    | okaymate     | 9000010   |
```

How do i make Table **Technician** and **Employee** become a user too, so they could use their information as username in a login form? Plus, i want each Id (not the "AutoIncrement" ID) of  **Technician** and **Employee**  would become the username.

How to manage the database like this?

or should i add password column in both tables? (Employee and Technician)

or should i make one table just like this?

**(new) Admin**

```
id | Id          | username | password     | phone_num | 
1  | AM10000     |  sim1    | 1234         | 9000010   | 
2  | AM10001     |  sim2    | luvcoding    | 9000010   |
3  | AM10002     |  sim3    | okaymate     | 9000010   |
4  | AM10003     |  EM10000 | test1        |  NULL     |
5  | AM10004     |  EM10001 | test2        |  NULL     |
6  | AM10005     | EM10002  | test3        |  NULL     |
7  | AM10006     | TE10000  | 1234         |  NULL     | 
8  | AM10007     | TE10001  | ok123        |  NULL     |
```

There is no relationship between Technician and Employee (stand-alone table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you would be better making your tables in normalization form as follows:

**Employees**

```
IdEmployee  | Employee | Address     | Phone_num 
EM10000     |  Jack    | wall st.    | 9000010  
EM10001     |  Paul    | elm st.     | 9000010  
EM10002     |  George  | ex  st .    | 9000010
```

**Technicians**

```
IdEmployee | TechName 
TE10000    | Gabut   
TE10001    | Polnaref
```

**Admins**

```
IdEmployee  |  Password  
TE10001     |  hashed_pass1 
EM10002     |  hashed_pass2
```

This makes sure you have no replicated data and ensures you can associate tables correctly by using foreign keys.

So if your admin has IdAdmin 'EM10002', to get the password of that employee with the following query:

```
// Will return a row with EM10002's password, which is 'hashed_pass2'. 
SELECT Password from Admins WHERE IdEmployee = EM10002
```

Here is another example of [foreign key](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) usage.

To understand normalization more, have a look at [this thread](https://beginnersbook.com/2015/05/normalization-in-dbms/).

Comment: why does Technician table have IdEmployee   ?

Comment: @gagantous I would guess you want to include your technicians as employees? Having the Employee ID connected to their Tech ID allows you to have access to their details in the Employees table. So if you want to find the address of Tech ID 'TE10000', the connected Employee ID to the Tech ID will allow you to access his address. Consider the Employee ID the link to your Employees table.

Comment: sorry, i would change my description, since Technician and Employee are different table that had no relationship (stand-alone table). So they only had relation with admin table @MinistryofChaps

Comment: So Technician is just like Employee table

Comment: @gagantous all you need to do is put Password in Admins and make a column called 'IDPersonell'(?) and insert the Employees/Technicians id in it, give me a second to edit my answer

Comment: @gagantous The answer has been fixed, you don't need an ID column because Employee ID's are already unique on both table. If the technicians have addresses and phone numbers too you can put them into the Technicians table. Making a column in admins called IDAdmin is redundant when you already have unique EmployeeIDs as the unique values.

Comment: @gagantous final thing, If you want a password for every employee (even if they are not and admin), all you need to do is make a password column in each employee and technicians table and remove the password column from admins.

Comment: so how about if in the table admin there is a username and password ( like my table Admin description ) that have username and password that from table admin itself ? ( no relation with 2 other table, Technician and Employee)

Comment: @gagantous that means that only users who are admins have passwords if the password column is only in admins. So if you want all users to have password you would put password columns in each employee and technician table... then if you want to check if user is an admin you check if their username is in the admin table then if true, verify their password.

Comment: thanks! really appreciate what you have explained to me and sorry for my bad grammar